# Injecting custom objects in Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, razor, blazor-webassembly

I want to "delegate" my code responsible for communications with the backend API to a separate class which I want to inject into my Blazor components just like I inject the `HttpClient`. I create the separate class and registere it in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IBackendComms, BackendComms>();
```

And I inject it in a component:

```
@inject BackendComms backendComms
```

But when I do this I get the "Unhandled error" after starting the project.

How do I properly inject my custom classes in razor files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your razor component, inject the Interface instead of the class:

```
@inject IBackendComms _backendComms
```

Then you can call any method the interface has from your component's code:

```
_backendComms.DoSomething(someParam);
```

Comment: You're right. Why didn't I think of that!? I guess I got influenced by HttpClient too much.